# Issues with Multiline SQL Update Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to replace multiple lines of text in an element of a MYSQL database.  The text is repeated 170 lines in the database.  Doing it through a database update is going to be a lot quicker than doing it manually 170 times.

The issue is when I submit the query in phpMySQLAdmin is that phpMySQLAdmin removes a lot of the spacing then the it doesn't match what's in the database so nothing is changed.

I tried adding putting the statement in a variable, but the line "DECLARE @COMPLEXSTRING varchar(1000);" gives off an "unrecognized statement type error"

Here is a slightly revised version of my SQL statement that I put into phpMySQLAdmin.

```
UPDATE `product_table` SET `extendeddescription` = REPLACE(`extendeddescription`, '<li>Factory recertified product</li>
<div align="left"><br />
  
  <div>NOTE: When a product wears a "factory recertified" label, it indicates a previously purchased item returned to the manufacturer. These items are factory-inspected and if needed, repairs are made to return the item to working condition.</div></div>', '<li><a href="https://website.com/recertified.html" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Factory recertified product</a></li>')
   WHERE `extendeddescription` LIKE '<li>Factory recertified product</li>
<div align="left"><br />
  
  <div>NOTE: When a product wears a "factory recertified" label, it indicates a previously purchased item returned to the manufacturer. These items are factory-inspected and if needed, repairs are made to return the item to working condition.<br /></div></div>';
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

UPDATE: I split my updates into multiple single line updates and left some of the HTML.  That worked.  I`m guessing that MySQL couldn`t handle the multiple lines.  When I a search for just the blob of text in phpMyAdmin it couldn`t find any instances of it as a complete multiline query.

Comment: you seem to be replacing the entire string, so why do you need `replace` - could you do `update set where`

Comment: you don declare user defined variables you SET them

Comment: can you provide a [mre] i doubt that phpmyadmin would remove anything

Comment: You can only declare variables in stored procedures.

Comment: It sounds like you've solved your own problem. Should we regard it as solved?